# Desplazar una imagen a voluntad en un boxlayout a mododo de carousel

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Tengo una lista de imágenes y necesito moverlas en modo carrusel cuando se cumpla cierta condición. El problema es que según tengo el código solo puedo mover una imagen en lugar de varias. Se deben mover de forma que según se desplace una, vaya apareciendo la otra sin espacio entre las fotos (como un carrusel). El primer problema que me encuentro con el código es que no sé como desplazar la primera imagen de forma fluida aunque he probado con kivy `clock schedule` pero no he podido implementarlo de forma correcta y lo deseché. Pero aun consiguiendo eso queda lo más importante que es hacer que la siguiente imagen aparezca.

He probado también con `Carousel` de kivy pero no sé como hacer que mediante un botón o mediante una condición o mediante una llamada a una función se desplacen las imágenes de una en una. Y además en este caso necesitaría deshabilitar el movimiento de las imágenes a través del ratón o a través de los dedos en android. Y por último cómo hago una llamada a la función desplazar de `Imagenes(Screen)`. ¡No soy capaz de hacerlo!

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<Pantalla>:
    Imagenes:

<Imagenes>:
    name: 'pantalla_imag'
    id: imag
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: screen_boxlayout
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        Image:
            id: fotos
            source: "imagen1.png"

        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)

            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Desplazar"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.desplazar()

""")

class Pantalla(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Imagenes(Screen):

    def desplazar(self):

        for i in range(10):
            self.ids.fotos.center_x += 10


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return Pantalla()

    #Imagenes.desplazar()    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

### Edición

Este código es el resultante de la ayuda de FJSevilla.
Todo funciona perfectamente excepto que necesito hacer una llamada a la función `desplazar_derecha()` de la `Clase Imagenes` y no se como hacerlo.
¿Qué es lo que habría que añadir en la `clase MyApp` para que la imagen se desplace sin utilizar el botón?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen



Builder.load_string("""

<Pantalla>:
    imagenes_screem: imagenes_screem
    Imagenes:
        name: "imagenes_screem"
        id: imagenes_screem


<Imagenes>:
    carousel: carousel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: screen_boxlayout
        NoTouchCarrousel:
            id: carousel
            direction: "right"

        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)

            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Anterior"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.desplazar_izquierda()
            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Siguiente"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: app.desplazar_desde_app()      # <<<<<
""")

class NoTouchCarrousel(Carousel):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            return True

class Pantalla(ScreenManager):
    imagenes_screem: ObjectProperty()


class Imagenes(Screen):
    carousel = ObjectProperty()

    def set_img_list(self, paths):
        self.carousel.clear_widgets()
        for src in paths:
            image = AsyncImage(source=src)
            self.carousel.add_widget(image)

    def desplazar_derecha(self):
        self.carousel.load_next()

    def desplazar_izquierda(self):
        self.carousel.load_previous()


class MyApp(App):
    pantalla = ObjectProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.pantalla = Pantalla()
        self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.set_img_list(["imagen1.png", "imagen2.png", "imagen3.png"])
        self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()
        return self.pantalla

    def desplazar_desde_app(self):
        self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi opinión lo más simple es usar el widget [Carousel](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#module-kivy.uix.carousel) que trae todo lo que necesitas (si no se me ha escapado algo) ademaś de traer animaciones por defecto para las transiciones.

Para pasar de una imagen a otra programáticamente basta con usar los métodos [`load_next()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#kivy.uix.carousel.Carousel.load_next) y [`load_previous()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#kivy.uix.carousel.Carousel.load_previous).

Evitar que se interaccione con el widget mediante el ratón o en dispositivo táctil, es trivial, por ejemplo basta con crear una clase que derive de `Carousel` y sobrescribir el método `on_touth_move`.

Un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_string("""

<Pantalla>:
    Imagenes:

<Imagenes>:
    name: 'pantalla_imag'
    id: imag
    carousel: carousel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: screen_boxlayout
        NoTouchCarrousel:
            id: carousel
            direction: "right"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "imagen1.png"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "imagen2.png"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "imagen3.png"

        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)

            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Anterior"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.desplazar_izquierda()
            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Siguiente"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.desplazar_derecha()
""")

class NoTouchCarrousel(Carousel):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            return True

class Pantalla(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Imagenes(Screen):
    carousel = ObjectProperty()
    def desplazar_derecha(self):
        self.carousel.load_next()

    def desplazar_izquierda(self):
        self.carousel.load_previous()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return Pantalla()

    #Imagenes.desplazar()    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

### Edición

Para poder llamar al método que quieras de la clase `Imagenes` desde `App`, su `ScreenManager` o otra `Screem`, puedes recurrir a muchas formas, una de ellas es simplemente exponer vía `id` y `ObjectProperty` la referencia de la ventana en la instancia de su `ScreenManager`.

Por otro lado, si tienes una lista de imágenes, la cual puede ser variable, solo añádelas mediante código Python en vez de definirías en el kv.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como hacer ambas cosas (obviamente existen más formas de conseguirlo), solo para mostrar como puedes hacerlo, se asigna la lista de imágenes y se llama a `desplazar_derecha` desde la `App`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen



Builder.load_string("""

<Pantalla>:
    imagenes_screem: imagenes_screem
    Imagenes:
        name: "imagenes_screem"
        id: imagenes_screem


<Imagenes>:
    carousel: carousel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: screen_boxlayout
        NoTouchCarrousel:
            id: carousel
            direction: "right"

        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)

            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Anterior"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.desplazar_izquierda()
            Button:
                id: desp_button
                text: "Siguiente"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: app.desplazar_desde_app()      # <<<<<
""")

class NoTouchCarrousel(Carousel):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            return True

class Pantalla(ScreenManager):
    imagenes_screem: ObjectProperty()


class Imagenes(Screen):
    carousel = ObjectProperty()

    def set_img_list(self, paths):
        self.carousel.clear_widgets()
        for src in paths:
            image = AsyncImage(source=src)
            self.carousel.add_widget(image)

    def desplazar_derecha(self):
        self.carousel.load_next()

    def desplazar_izquierda(self):
        self.carousel.load_previous()


class MyApp(App):
    pantalla = ObjectProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.pantalla = Pantalla()
        self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.set_img_list(["imagen1.png", "imagen2.png", "imagen3.png"])
        return self.pantalla

    def desplazar_desde_app(self):
        self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Tu código soluciona en parte mis necesidades. Y si yo quisiera llamar a la función ´´´desplazar_derecha´´´ desde por ejemplo la clase myApp o desde cualquier otra clase? He probado a llamarla creando un objeto imagen pero no ha funcionado: ´´´imagen1 = Imagenes()´´´   ´´´imagen1.desplazar_derecha()´´´ Y si en vez de tres imágenes son una lista de ellas?

Comment: Si creas un nuevo objeto Imagenes llamarás al método de instancia de ese objeto, no al método del objeto que representa tu widget. He editado la respuesta intentando dar respuesta a tus dos problemas, mira a ver que tal.

Comment: Y entonces llegados a este punto como llamo a ´desplazar_derecha´ desde la clase ´MyApp´ o desde cualquier otra clase? Así, tal y como está se sigue llamando desde el botón. Lo que necesito es que en cualquier momento pueda hacer una llamada para que la imagen se desplace, pero sin utilizar el botón. Dicho de otra forma, todo el código lo voy a introducir en la clase MyApp y necesitaré acceder a la función ´desplazar_derecha´ ( o izquierda) en cualquier momento sin utilizar botones.

Comment: Toni desde la `App` se llama igual que se hace desde el método `desplazar_desde_app` que es el que llama el botón, es decir `self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()` o `self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_izquierda()`. He usado el botón y `desplazar_desde_app`  solo como ejemplo reproducible.

Comment: Sí`, es lo primero que probé pero no funcionó. Me sale esto: ´self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()
 NameError: name 'self' is not defined´ He copiado tu código íntegro en otro archivo y así me funciona con ese error. Si no pongo `self.pantalla.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()` me funciona perfectamente con el botón.

Comment: `self` es la referencia a la instancia de MyApp, debes realizar la llamada desde un método de instancia como es `desplazar_derecha` o `build`. Nunca jamás ejecutes código en el cuerpo de la clase a no ser que sea para definir o asignar atributos de clase. `self.root.imagenes_screem.desplazar_derecha()` es otra forma de acceder una vez que `buid` retorne. Si no te aclaras, edita la pregunta y añade tu nuevo código al final, sin eliminar lo anterior

Comment: Ya he editado. La verdad es que no me aclaro porque todavía no entiendo el concepto clase / objeto. Con python y clases sencillas no tengo problema pero cuando me meto en berenjenales de kivy no sé por donde salir. La documentación de kivy solo sirve si eres un experto. Si eres principiante estás vendido.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94678/discussion-between-fjsevilla-and-toni).